# Firebase - Web - Testing security rules - Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am trying to follow the firebase docs to test security rules ([Build unit tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests)), specifically the [video](https://youtu.be/VDulvfBpzZE).

But an error does not allow me to continue... [this](https://youtu.be/VDulvfBpzZE?t=636).

My emulators are ok... but anything is not working because with the emulators activated, I get the same error as before. (...the client is offline)

[image]

Anyone can help me?

The testing code is the same as in the video (I have changed the project id with 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' to keep it private):

```js
const assert = require('assert')
const firebase = require('@firebase/testing')

const MY_PROJECT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

describe('Our social app', () => {
  it('Understands basic addition', () => {
    assert.strictEqual(2 + 2, 4)
  })

  it('Can read items in the read-only collection', async () => {
    const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID }).firestore()
    const testDoc = db.collection('readonly').doc('testDoc')
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.get())
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had changed Firestore port to 8090 in firebase.json

```json
"emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8090
    },
```

But the method **initializaTestApp** sets 8080 as default. It was invoked in the testing file **test.js**

```js
const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID }).firestore()
```

A **console.log** of **db** shows the problem (port 8080)

[image]